# Texto no me genera en el PDF PHP

Tags: php

¿Qué está mal en este código?

```
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$documento = $_POST['documento'];
$cargo = $_POST['cargo'];
$rh = $_POST['rh'];
$empresa = $_POST['empresa'];

//nuevas variables para carta presentacion.

$fecha_ingreso = $_POST['fecha_ingreso'];
$empresa_dirige = $_POST['empresa_dirige'];
$direccion = $_POST['direccion'];
$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
$eps = $_POST['eps'];
$arl = $_POST['arl'];
$fondo = $_POST['fondo'];
$caja = $_POST['caja'];
```

Dice que tengo un error:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: nombre in /workspace/Main.php on line 5

Y así en todas las lineas.

Comment: Significa que en `$_POST` no hay nada que contenga el índice `nombre`. Si los datos vienen de un formulario o de Ajax o de una URL debes verificar cómo estás nombrado los elementos. ¿De dónde vienen los datos? Para verificar lo que hay en el POST puedes hacer un `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: No uses el área de respuestas para añadir datos de la pregunta. Tienes que [edit]  para agregar lo que haga falta. En tu HTML parece que hay dos `form`, pero hay uno que no tiene la etiqueta de apertura ¿? Acláranos eso y muestra también de qué modo pasas los datos al servidor, si es por Ajax, muestra el código Javascript que usas.

Answer (score 1):

Los datos vienen de un archivo HTML:

```
                            <!-- Documento -->
                            <div class="md-form">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="documento" required pattern="[0-9]{5,15}" id="documento" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Cédula" requiered />
                            </div>
                            <!-- Cargo -->
                            <div class="md-form">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" title="Solo texto en  letras" name="cargo" id="cargo" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Cargo" requiered />
                            </div>
                            <!-- RH -->
                            <div class="md-form">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="rh" id="rh" autocomplete="off" placeholder="R.H." requiered />
                            </div>
                            <!-- Empresa -->
                            <div class="md-form">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" title="Solo texto en  letras" pattern="[A-Za-z ]{2,30}" name="empresa" id="empresa" placeholder="Empresa" requiered />
                            </div>
                            <!-- Fecha ingreso -->
                            <div class="md-form">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" title="Formato ej: 23 de Abril de 2018" name="fecha_ingreso" id="fecha_ingreso" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Fecha del ingréso" requiered />
                            </div>
                            <!-- Empresa dirige -->
                            <div class="md-form">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" title="Solo texto en  letras" name="empresa_dirige" id="empresa_dirige" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Empresa a donde se dirige" requiered />
                            </div>
                            <!-- Dirección -->
                            <div class="md-form">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" title="Dirección Ej: Cr48C # 68-39 Sur" name="direccion" id="direccion" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Dirección del empleado" requiered />
                            </div>
                            <!-- Teléfono -->
                            <div class="md-form">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" title="Solo texto en  letras" pattern="[0-9]{5,20}" name="telefono" id="telefono" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Teléfono del empleado" requiered />
                            </div>
                            <!-- EPS -->
                            <div class="md-form">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" title="Solo texto en  letras" pattern="[A-Za-z ]{2,30}" name="eps" id="eps" placeholder="EPS" requiered />
                            </div>
                            <!-- ARL -->
                            <div class="md-form">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" title="Solo texto en  letras" pattern="[A-Za-z ]{2,30}" name="arl" id="arl" placeholder="ARL" requiered />
                            </div>
                            <!-- Fondo -->
                            <div class="md-form">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" title="Fondo de pensiones y cesantias" name="fondo" id="fondo" placeholder="Fondo de pensiones" requiered />
                            </div>
                            <!-- Caja -->
                            <div class="md-form">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" title="Caja de compensación familiar" name="caja" id="caja" placeholder="Caja de compensación" requiered />
                            </div>

                            <!-- boton para generar la carta y el carnet -->
                            <button id="generarcar" type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-rounded btn-block z-depth-0 my-4 waves-effect">
                                Generar Carnet y Carta
                            </button>

                            <!-- boton para enviar a la base de datos -->
                            <button id="Enviar" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-rounded btn-block z-depth-0 my-4 waves-effect" type="button">
                                Guardar
                            </button>

                            <a href="/includes/conexionExcel.php" id="EnviarExcel" class="excel">
                                Exportar a Excel
                            </a>

                        </form><form id="Formulario" class="text-center" style="color: #757575;" method="post" action="includes/generar.php" target="blank">
                            <!-- Nombre -->
                            <div class="md-form mt-3">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" title="Solo texto en  letras, nombre y apellido." pattern="[A-Za-z ]{6,80}" name="nombre" id="nombre" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Nombre" requiered />
                            </div>

                            <!-- Documento -->
                            <div class="md-form">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="documento" required pattern="[0-9]{5,15}" id="documento" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Cédula" requiered />
                            </div>
                            <!-- Cargo -->
                            <div class="md-form">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" title="Solo texto en  letras" name="cargo" id="cargo" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Cargo" requiered />
                            </div>
                            <!-- RH -->
                            <div class="md-form">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="rh" id="rh" autocomplete="off" placeholder="R.H." requiered />
                            </div>
                            <!-- Empresa -->
                            <div class="md-form">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" title="Solo texto en  letras" pattern="[A-Za-z ]{2,30}" name="empresa" id="empresa" placeholder="Empresa" requiered />
                            </div>
                            <!-- Fecha ingreso -->
                            <div class="md-form">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" title="Formato ej: 23 de Abril de 2018" name="fecha_ingreso" id="fecha_ingreso" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Fecha del ingréso" requiered />
                            </div>
                            <!-- Empresa dirige -->
                            <div class="md-form">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" title="Solo texto en  letras" name="empresa_dirige" id="empresa_dirige" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Empresa a donde se dirige" requiered />
                            </div>
                            <!-- Dirección -->
                            <div class="md-form">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" title="Dirección Ej: Cr48C # 68-39 Sur" name="direccion" id="direccion" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Dirección del empleado" requiered />
                            </div>
                            <!-- Teléfono -->
                            <div class="md-form">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" title="Solo texto en  letras" pattern="[0-9]{5,20}" name="telefono" id="telefono" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Teléfono del empleado" requiered />
                            </div>
                            <!-- EPS -->
                            <div class="md-form">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" title="Solo texto en  letras" pattern="[A-Za-z ]{2,30}" name="eps" id="eps" placeholder="EPS" requiered />
                            </div>
                            <!-- ARL -->
                            <div class="md-form">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" title="Solo texto en  letras" pattern="[A-Za-z ]{2,30}" name="arl" id="arl" placeholder="ARL" requiered />
                            </div>
                            <!-- Fondo -->
                            <div class="md-form">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" title="Fondo de pensiones y cesantias" name="fondo" id="fondo" placeholder="Fondo de pensiones" requiered />
                            </div>
                            <!-- Caja -->
                            <div class="md-form">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" title="Caja de compensación familiar" name="caja" id="caja" placeholder="Caja de compensación" requiered />
                            </div>

                            <!-- boton para generar la carta y el carnet -->
                            <button id="generarcar" type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-rounded btn-block z-depth-0 my-4 waves-effect">
                                Generar Carnet y Carta
                            </button>

                            <!-- boton para enviar a la base de datos -->
                            <button id="Enviar" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-rounded btn-block z-depth-0 my-4 waves-effect" type="button">
                                Guardar
                            </button>

                            <a href="/includes/conexionExcel.php" id="EnviarExcel" class="excel">
                                Exportar a Excel
                            </a>

                        </form>
```

Comment: No uses la zona de respuesta para agregar cosas a la pregunta para eso intenta [Editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/311926/edit) tu pregunta y haces los respectivos cambios. Puedes hacer el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que aprendas más sobre el sitio y ganes tu primera medalla.